# What if the Sun were suddenly 2/3 as bright?

Tags: climate, sunlight

The amount of solar energy received by Earth is reduced to 67% of the current amount, uniformly across the Earth and throughout the EM spectrum. The mass of the sun stays the same.

One month later, what are the physical consequences?

Specifically, what is the average global temperature, roughly? And presumably inland areas are frigid, but how much so, and are coastal areas still habitable or have the oceans frozen over considerably?

Comment: 2/3 as bright but no change to its mass?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus :) No mass change. I'm asking specifically because every question I find that _does_ reduce mass just has answers like "the planets fly out of their orbits, the end".

Comment: @user535733 It's basically a physics problem, no? I can see that maybe it should be migrated to another site, but that I don't see how this is too broad.

Comment: As a first estimate, avg global temperature would drop from 16 Celsius to  -11 Celsius - this would cause catastrophic cooling, the end result would essentially be a snowball earth because the decreased albedo with large ice sheet would lower the temperature even further than the estimate based solely on the 4th power Stefan Boltzman law

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think if we go back more than 1 billion years the internal energy of the Earth will be too great to neglect though. Wasn't it a ball of lava up until 3.5 billion ago?

Comment: Predicting the amount of cooling after 30 days is difficult because there are so many non-linear effects to be considered.

Comment: @user535733 You changed my question from "one month later" to "20 years later". One month is pretty straightforward. It shouldn't be so cold that everywhere is inhospitable, certainly a whole system of geothermal bunkers hasn't been developed, etc. But maybe it's too cold for far-inland settlements, and probably crops would fail globally (but maybe not, hence me asking here).

Comment: @GaryWalker Yeah, best I can get is that the equilibrium temperature will be between -15C and -10C. But how long it takes to reach equilibrium could be centuries (millennia?). And whether this dimming occurs in Austral or Boreal Summer has a large effect after one month I'd guess, since the ratios of land and ocean coverage are so different across hemispheres.

Comment: @Sam - actually, I believe the long term equilibrium temperature would be much lower. Avg. albedo of earth is about 0.30, snow can be as low as 0.1, then with the frigid air, there would be little cloud cover, making the lost of heat considerably faster. All non-linear, hard to predict kind of stuff, but I know that some people have suggested that under full snowball earth conditions, the temperature at the equator would be more like Antarctica today.

Comment: Diurnal ocean temperature range is about 6 Celsius, Land range is general about 8 C or more. As a first approximation, I would expect ocean temperature to drop about 2% (absolute) and land 3% (absolute) each day, at least until freezing temperatures are reached - because of the large heat change required to freeze water. In practical terms, pretty much everything would be freezing (or colder) within 10 days - put on your long johns.

Comment: I'm gonna play devil's advocate and disagree with the VTC. All of the author's questions are directly related to temperature, which is so straightforward that multiple comments have already answered the question. Though the wording "what are the physical consequences" may seem broad, the OP is very clearly concerned about temperature specifically.

Comment: @SurpriseDog The edit was incorrect. "Were" is the third-person singular subjunctive of "is".

Answer (score 7):

Taking a bunch of information from https://www.firsttheseedfoundation.org/resource/tomatosphere/background/sunlight-mars-enough-light-mars-grow-tomatoes/

It looks like Mars receives about 590 W/m2 solar irradiance at the surface but Earth gets 1000 W/m2 so we're at 59% (almost 2/3).

Mars can get as low as [-200°F but as high as 80°F](https://www.scholastic.com/teachers/articles/teaching-content/mars/)(-130 to +25°C) so we would notice that the Earth is cooler within about 8 minutes 20 seconds (due to speed of light) than it used to be; I would guess at least a 10 degree drop. We wouldn't immediately freeze because unlike Mars, Earth has an atmosphere and gigantic bodies of water to retain heat.

On Earth there exists a place called Devon Island which resembles the solar irradiance of Mars which much better resembles what we would experience long-term.

> Devon Island is the largest uninhabited island on Earth. It is found at 75oN and has  surface characteristics that strongly resemble the surface of Mars. Being so far north, Devon Island has solar irradiance similar to the solar irradiation on the Martian Equator. Except for a brief period in June, the intensity of the Sun on Devon Island never exceeds the solar intensity on Mars
>
> Will tomatoes grow inside a greenhouse on Devon Island or will solar energy need to be collected, stored in batteries, and then “concentrated” using artificial heat and light?
>
> **Growing tomatoes with ‘concentrated’ solar energy**
>
> Although the light intensity (near local noon only) on Devon Island is similar to that expected on the Martian Equator, the duration of daylight during this time is 24 hours per day because of its high latitude (above the Arctic Circle).
>
> On Mars, near the equator, the duration of daylight is about 12 hours, followed by approximately 12 hours of darkness. A Martian greenhouse will need to be well insulated to avoid huge temperature drops at night.
>
> Perhaps a combination of passive greenhouse heating during the day, supplemented by electrical heating and lighting at night will be required to provide a suitable growing environment for plants to be grown on Mars.
>
> Collecting and storing solar energy is an extremely inefficient process. A major fraction of the energy is lost as heat long before it is made available as light energy for plant growth.

Wikipedia says that the temperature range on Devon Island ranges from [−58°F to 50°F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devon_Island)(-50 to +10°C) and is used in the [Flashline Mars Arctic Research Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashline_Mars_Arctic_Research_Station) to simulate and study the survivability of life on Mars.

Overall, it seems survivable for any sufficiently prepared economy but if this drastic change catches you with your pants down then you have very little chance of surviving long-term.

I would imagine that many of the survivorship tactics presented in [If The Sun Went Out, How Long Could Life On Earth Survive?](https://www.popsci.com/science/article/2013-07/if-sun-went-out-how-long-could-life-earth-survive/) would gain immediate popularity such as geothermal energy to keep dwellings warm.

Comment: Wouldn't our atmosphere have a stronger greenhouse effect than Mars', making it noticeably warmer? On top of that, Earth's interior is still hot, and Mars' is not. You're right that it would get colder; I'm just knitpicking how much.

Comment: The oceans are also a heat collector and will take quite a while to cool down. I think the decline of temperature will be gradual rather than immediate.

Comment: @CAEJones Good call. I edited my post so that it has less of an "end of the world ice age" vibe.

Comment: @Hyfnae Thanks, edited.